# An order that lacks "infinite" transitivity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, relations, order-theory

The ordering on the real line "$<$" possesses the property that if we have a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $a_n < a_{n+1}$ and if we have a finite limit $a$, then $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < \dots < a$ and we can conclude that $a_1 < a$ - even though transitivity of "$<$" is a statement of finitely many elements.

Can we have an ordering, not necessarily on the reals, where "infinite" transitivity is not necessarily followed? We'd keep all the other properties: anti-symmetric and transitive; but we could have an $"a"$ such that $a_0$ and $a$ are incomparable but there exists an infinite chain  such that $a_0 < a_1 < \dots < a$. Have these orderings been discussed already?

Attempt: An attempt I've thought about is taking the extended reals ($\mathbb{R} \cup{\{\pm \infty\}}$) and defining the normal order $<$ on the finite numbers but every finite number is "greater than" $\infty$, $-\infty > \infty$ , and every finite number is "less than" $-\infty$. So if we had a sequence diverging to $\infty$ , we'd simultaneously arrive at the smallest element while getting larger; which wouldn't be infinite transitive. However, I'm curious about a case where our limit $a$ is still larger than at least one element in our sequence.

Motivation: Went on a wikipedia rabbit hole after reviewing Zorn's lemma.

Comment: What is a “limit” if not some kind of upper bound?

Comment: Take the sequence $a_n=1+1/n$ and let $a=0$. There, not an upper bound.

Comment: @Asaf you know full well I mean “of a strictly increasing sequence in some kind of totally ordered set” :)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: I'm tired, but fine, I'll take this seriously.

Comment: Clarifying your requirements for compatibility between the order and the topology in which you're taking limits will probably get you most of the way to an answer.

Comment: @Karl What if I wanted to just consider infinite chains under this order, instead of looking at limits of sequences? I know this is irrelevant to my original question, but I'm curious if this might be easier.

Comment: @Sean The point then (in lieu of introducing some auxiliary topology) is what is a limit? What is an “a”? For any $a$, if $a>a_n$ for some $n$ then $a>a_i$ for all $i\le n$, by (finite) transitivity. If $a\not > a_n$ for some $n$, then $a\not > a_i$ for all $i\ge n.$ (Note none of this assumes the order is total.) In the latter case, what does $a$ have to do with the tail of the sequence? “Infinite transitivity” just doesn’t seem coherent.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen So, I would need to consider an order that is not total?

Comment: The question as currently written is essentially meaningless since you have not explained what you mean by an "$a$".

Comment: @Sean No, my point was that what I said holds just as well for partial orders. I only used transitivity.

Comment: Can you state precisely what the $\dots<a$ part of your expression $a_0 < a_1 < \dots < a$ means? I'd normally interpret it as saying that $a_i<a$ for every $i$, but that's clearly not your intent.

Comment: I need to point out that $a_0 < a$ doe *not* use an infinite number of transitives.  We are given that $a_i< a_j$ and the $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = a$.  From that we can (and do) prove that $a_j < a$ for all $a_j$ (this proof uses *finite* transitivity).  And that is how we know that $a_0 < a$.  The statement $a_0< a_1< .... <a$ means nothing more or less than i) $a_i$ is increasing and ii) $a_i < a$ for all $a_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the most generous interpretation of your question, it seems you are considering a partial order $\leq$ on some topological space $X$, and you are asking if strictly increasing sequences must converge to an upper bound, if the order is "continuous" in that sense.

To put it simply, the answer is absolutely not. Without imposing, a priori, some relationship between $\leq$ and the topology of $X$, there is no reason to believe that such a property would hold, and in a precise sense, it usually won't. Similar to how most functions are not continuous, likewise most total orders will not be "continuous" in this way. For instance, the Well Ordering theorem guarantees the existence of some well order relation on the reals, but not only will this ordering disagree with the usual order relation of the real numbers, it will be "discontinuous" at every point.

Your attempt can be adjusted slightly to give an example which is more intuitive. Define $X:=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$, and define $\leq$ as a total order on $X$ in the expected way, so that $-\infty$ is the global minimum. Moreover, provide $X$ with the topology that results from taking $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$, and gluing together $-\infty\sim\infty$. In this topology, any strictly increasing and unbounded sequence in $X$ limits to $-\infty$, which I think is what you wanted. The identification of $-\infty\sim\infty$ is necessary, since otherwise the positive infinity "gets in the way" by absorbing all the unbounded increasing sequences, preventing a counter example. We also need to define the ordering *after* the identification, since otherwise we end up in a situation where $-\infty<-\infty$, which is not allowed.

An equivalent example is to let $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}$, which is the unit circle. Give $X$ the usual topology as a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. As for the order, for each point $p\in X$, define $\arg(p)$ as the unique value $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ for which $p=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$. Now define the ordering $\leq$ of $X$ so that $p\leq q \iff \arg(p)\leq \arg(q)$. In this case, we have the point $(1,0)$ as the global minimum of $X$, and we get our counter example by approaching this point from below the x-axis. This example is actually the same as the previous one, under isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not good. You've simply switched the labels of $\infty$ and $-\infty$. You still treat the "divergence to $\infty$" under the standard order of the real numbers, but then you're using your modified one.

So in reality, you've actually defined two orders which a priori have nothing to do with one another, and then you claim that an upper bound in one order is a lower bound in another. That's not what you've asked, though. You've asked about *an order*, singular, with some properties.

But what you've asked is impossible. An upper bound is by definition greater than, or equal to, each an every element of the sequence (or subset). The infinite transitivity is not really infinite in any kind of way, except that the set of points below $a$ is infinite, since it includes all the $a_n$s.

Now, orders generate a topology by using cones, that is "all points above" and "all points below" a certain point in the order. For linear orders this is a particularly nice topology. In any case, if you have an increasing sequence, a limit (if such limit exists) is going to be an upper bound in that topology. Indeed, the limits are exactly the minimal upper bounds (and in a linear order, there can be at most one such minimal, and indeed the topology is Hausdorff, and hence nice).

Comment: So, I should look into non-linear orders? Could you explain how your answer for linear orders refutes the existence of any order that satisfies this property? I never said that the order has to be a total order.

Answer (score 0):

Simply take $x<y$ for all $x,y\in[0,1)$ and $0\sim 1$.

Then, $0<0.5<0.75<...$ but at the limit $0\sim 1$.